# AttributeError: 'Tensor' has no attribute: 'backwards'

Tags: pytorch, loss-function

I'm posting this question for those who made the same error I did. I got this error when trying to compute my gradients:

```
criterion = torch.nn.CrossEntropyLoss()
loss = criterion(y_hat, y_truth)
loss.backwards()
```

Answer (score 40, accepted):

It's `loss.backward()`, not `loss.backwards()`.